# Perform Inner Join on 2 Files of type IEnumerable<XElement>

Tags: c#, linq, join, ienumerable, xelement

Lets say I have 2 files of type IEnumerable`<XElement`>. How would I perform an inner join and/or a group join on them? I have tried the following but the .Join method does not work on IEnumerable's. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var innerjoin = file1.Join(file2, c => file1.Elements("OrderID"), o => file2.Elements("OrderID"), (c, o) => new { Customer = c, Order = o });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `file1` and `file2` contains `IEnumerable<XElement>` where each `XElement` has a child element `OrderID`, you can do join by `OrderID` value like this :

```
var innerjoin = file1.Join(file2, 
                            c => (string)c.Element("OrderID"), 
                            o => (string)o.Element("OrderID"),
                            (c, o) => new {Customer = c, Order = o});
```

Or using the equivalent query syntax :

```
var innerjoin = from c in file1
                join o in file2 
                   on (string)c.Element("OrderID") equals (string)o.Element("OrderID")
                select new {Customer = c, Order = o};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below from webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9.  You probably want to join on the actual ID number and not just the element name.

```
           var innerjoin = from f1 in file1.Elements("OrderID")
                            join f2 in file2.Elements("OrderID") on f1 equals f2
                            select new { file1, file2 };​
```